# Alert blocking "required field" pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alert

I am making a form that when filled out is creates an alert telling you that it was a success and where the user is about to be redirected to. The problem is that this alert seems to be "blocking" the chrome "please fill out this field" pop-up for input fields with the `required` attribute that were not filled in.

It is (to my knowledge) only an Chrome problem. IE still shows the pop-up after the alert, and I have not been able to try Firefox.

For example

```
<form method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="javascript:alert('All done')">
</form>
```

The best result would be to only show the alert if all the required fields are filled in.

Comment: `onclick` is the wrong event to listen to. `submit` on the form is appropriate, but you shouldn't be adding inline JavaScript anyway.

Comment: Your right! An the only reason I have the inline js is for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `onclick` and add `onsubmit` to the `form` tag:

```
<form method="post" action="sendemail.php" onsubmit="javascript:alert('All done')">
    <input type="text" name="name" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

`onsubmit` only fires once the form is submitted, which won't happen if a `required` input isn't filled in. `onclick` always fires when clicking the submit button, even if all fields aren't correct.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that there was such an attribute until now.

Comment: @ZacharyElkins No problem. Remember to mark this answer if it worked for you, thank you!

Comment: I've been trying to but you have to wait 10 minutes before marking a comment as the answer. (5 minutes to go!)

Comment: Oh yes, forgot about that. :)

Comment: Huh, for some reason it worked but and shows the "field required" popup, but when I actually fill it out it redirects without showing the alert! @JacquesMarais

Comment: @ZacharyElkins Updated answer to only redirect once the alert is done.

Comment: I see. Thanks again!